# how to compare the equality of two list elements on ONE TO ONE basis using java8 streams?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

how to compare the equality of two list elements on ONE TO ONE basis using java8 streams?

```
    inputNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    inputNameList.add("ram");
    inputNameList.add("shyam");
    inputNameList.add("hari");      

    outputNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    outputNameList.add("ram");
    outputNameList.add("shyaM");
    outputNameList.add("ram");
```

when this two lists are compared then the result is 1 because only inputNameList.get(0).equals(outputNameList.get(0))  == true;

Comment: What does `1` represent?  The index of the first element which is not equal?  the number of matches?  An example can illustrate your requirements but it cannot define them.

Comment: If only `zip` were, that could've been written like as `zip(input, output, Object::equals).filter(e -> e).count()`.

Answer (score 4):

Seems that you want to find the position of the first mismatch or the list size. You can do this using the stream of indices like this (assuming lists have equal length):

```
int nMatches = IntStream
         .range(0, inputNameList.size())
         .filter(idx -> !inputNameList.get(idx).equals(outputNameList.get(idx)))
         .findFirst()
         .orElse(inputNameList.size());
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both the lists will have equal number of elements, you can make use of `IntStream` as:

```
List<String> inputNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
inputNameList.add("ram");
inputNameList.add("shyam");
inputNameList.add("hari");

List<String> outputNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
outputNameList.add("ram");
outputNameList.add("shyaM");
outputNameList.add("ram");

IntStream.range(0,inputNameList.size()).forEach(i -> {
    if(inputNameList.get(i).equals(outputNameList.get(i))) System.out.println(i);
});
```

This will print the index when elements are equal at that index in the lists. You can modify it as per your requirement.